# How to get JSF working with spring-boot app in docker container?

Tags: jsf, docker, spring-boot

I have an app built with spring-boot 1.4.0 and JSF 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.13) running on embedded tomcat (8.5).

When I run the app **locally**, it works fine - regardless of whether I start it from my IDE, with `mvn spring-boot:run` or `java -jar target/myapp.jar`

However, when I start the app **inside a docker container** (using docker 1.12.1) everything works **except** for the JSF pages. For example the spring-boot-actuator pages like `/health` work just fine but when trying to access `/home.xhtml` (a JSF page) I get:

---

**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for `/error`, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Oct 12 09:33:33 GMT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
`/home.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource`

---

I use `io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin` to build the docker image (based on alpine with openjdk-8-jre), which includes the build artifact under `/maven` inside the docker container and `java -jar /maven/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar` to start the app.

I am using port 9000 instead of the standard tomcat port (8080) and this is also exposed by the docker image.

I already compared both the local jar and the one included in the docker container and they both have the same content.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XHTML files and the rest of the JSF files was placed in the wrong directory.

At least when using `<packaging>jar</packaging>` it appears that all JSF stuff must be placed under `src/main/resources/META-INF` instead of `src/main/webapp` where most IDEs will automatically place it.

When JSF stuff is in `src/main/webapp` it does not get included (or not in the right place) into the spring-boot-repackaged jar file.

My `src/main/resources` looks like this now:

```
src
└── main
    └── resources
        ├── application.yml
        └── META-INF
            ├── faces-config.xml
            └── resources
                ├── administration
                │   └── userlist.xhtml
                ├── css
                │   └── default.css
                ├── images
                │   └── logo.png
                └── home.xhtml
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same issue. Running the Spring Boot application directly from maven or from a packaged WAR file worked fine, but running it from a Docker container lead to the same problem.

Actually, the problem for me was that accessing dynamic resources (JSPs or the like) always lead to trying to show the error page, which could not be found and therefore a 404 was returned, but static content was returned correctly.

It sounds silly, but it turned out for me that it matters whether you call the packaged WAR file ".war" or ".jar" when you start it. I used a Docker example for Spring Boot which (for some reason) names the WAR file "app.jar". If you do that, you run into this issue in the Docker container. If you call it "app.war" instead, it works fine.

This has nothing to do with Docker, by the way. The same happens if you try to start the application directly on the host when it has a .jar extension (unless you start it in a location where the needed resources are lying around in an extracted manner).

Starting my application with

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar application.jar
```

leads to the error. Renaming from .jar to .war and using

```
java -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar application.war
```

made it work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was copying the webapp folder to META-INF while adding resources

```
<resource>
  <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
  <targetPath>META-INF/resources</targetPath>
</resource>
```

and then add change the documentRoot to the path where it is available in the docker container:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory>
  webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return factory -> factory.setDocumentRoot(new File("/workspace/META-INF/resources"));
}
```

now i can use jsf pages while using `spring-boot:build-image` and jar packaging

ps: i still had a bunch of exceptions, which where gone after upgrading spring boot+liquibase to newest version, but i think this does not belong to this topic